# How to change hash key from array of hashes in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

Given:

```
data = [
  {"votable_id"=>1150, "user_ids"=>"1,2,3,4,5,6,"},
  {"votable_id"=>1151, "user_ids"=>"55,66,34,23,56,7,8"}
]
```

This is the expected result. Array should have first 5 elements.

```
data = [
  {"votable_id"=>1150, "user_ids"=>["1","2","3","4","5"]},
  {"votable_id"=>1151, "user_ids"=>["55","66","34","23","56","7",8"]}
]
```

This is what I tried :

```
data.map{|x| x['user_ids'] = x['user_ids'].split(',').first(5)}
```

Any other optimized solution ?

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you have?

Comment: It is big array. Almost 1000 count.

Comment: What are you optimizing for? Performance? Memory consumption? Where is the data coming from – for example, a file, a database or user input? The `.first(5)` will not generate the expected result, is that an error or okay? Is it okay to change the/overwrite original array?

Comment: The data is coming from db. It has to be displayed on F.E. I need to pick first 5 users from the array. No we cannot overwrite the array.

Comment: Part of @spickermann's comment  is more-or-less asking whether the expected result of `data[1]["user_ids"]` should be `["55","66","34","23","56"]` instead of `["55","66","34","23","56","7",8"]`.

Comment: "The data is coming from db". Are you really storing comma separated strings? Not doing that in the first place is *the optimized soution*. Anything else is just damage control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `.map` and `.tap` like this

```
data.map do |h|
 h.tap { |m_h| m_h["user_ids"]= m_h["user_ids"].split(',').first(5)}
end
```

Comment: Good answer if `data` is to be mutated but a comment on the question by the OP indicates `data` is not mutated. It is confusing because the OP wrote `data = [...]` as the "expected result", suggesting that `data` is to be mutated.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [
    {"votable_id"=>1150, "user_ids"=>"1,2,3,4,5,6,"},
    {"votable_id"=>1151, "user_ids"=>"55,66,34,23,56,7,8"}
]
```

Code

```
h=data.map do |h|
  h["user_ids"]=[h["user_ids"].split(',').first(5)].flatten
  h
end

p h
```

Output

```
[{"votable_id"=>1150, "user_ids"=>["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]}, {"votable_id"=>1151, "user_ids"=>["55", "66", "34", "23", "56"]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data.map { |h| h.merge("user_ids"=>h["user_ids"].split(',').first(5)) }
  #=> [{"votable_id"=>1150, "user_ids"=>["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]},
  #    {"votable_id"=>1151, "user_ids"=>["55", "66", "34", "23", "56"]}]
```

See [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge). This leaves `data` unchanged. To modify (or *mutate*) `data` use [Hash#merge!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) (aka `update`). `h.merge(k=>v)` is a shortcut for `h.merge({ k=>v })`.